# How do I install Ubuntu Core 16 on the Beaglebone Black?

Tags: ubuntu-core, beagleboard

I am trying to install Ubuntu Core 16 on the Beaglebone black, which is supposedly supported.

I can't seem to find the documentation on how to utilise the beagleblack [gadget snap](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/gadget-snaps/).

I also don't see a beaglebone black image for [download](http://releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/16/).

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beaglebone Black is not an officially supported platform. One of the Ubuntu Core team members has [published](http://people.canonical.com/~ogra/snappy/all-snaps/daily-stable/current/ubuntu-core-16-beaglebone.img.xz) a developer image that can be used to explore and learn.

Comment: Thanks! Then may I know what is the purpose of the [beagleblack gadget snap](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/gadget-snaps/)? How is it related to Ubuntu Core on the Beaglebone Black?

Comment: This seems to be a debian image. Is there any documentation for this?

Comment: @razorsniper, you can read more about the Gadget snap here- https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/wiki/Gadget-snap